# Gnuplot shows garbage when trying to save picture

Tags: gnuplot

When I input the following into the gnuplot window:

```
set xlabel "x"; set ylabel "y"; 
plot "rk1000.dat" with lines, "teor1000.dat" with lines
```

The result is a nice plot. However, when I attempt to save it as a .png file, the result is not so nice. After typing

```
set xlabel "x"; set ylabel "y"; set terminal png size 800,600; 
plot "rk1000.dat" with lines, "teor1000.dat" with lines
```

the result is gnuplot spitting out garbage characters and doing nothing. Here's a screenshot: [image]

How do I fix this? Not even an hour ago I had no problem saving my plots.

Comment: It's not garbage, it's the content of the image that you should save to a file instead of printing it on the terminal.

Comment: Then why did the exact same command work for a previous plot, and not for this one? That's what so weird to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `set output` in your script to make gnuplot redirect the output to a file:

```
set terminal png size 800,600
set output "plot.png"
plot "rk1000.dat" with lines, "teor1000.dat" with lines
```

If you are creating png images using gnuplot, the "pngcairo" terminal produces better-looking results. Try `set terminal` to see the list of available terminals.

Answer (score 2):

Just save the output to a png file:

```
gnuplot script.gp > picture.png
```

Search the web for "redirection" if you want to know more.

Answer (score -2):

you should plot first then set term

ex

"plot '../log/test_coverage_${atpg_mode}.log.tmp' title 'Ori ATPG' w lp lt 3 pt 9"

"set terminal png font \"/usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf\" 9"     ; # save the image as the png format

"set terminal png size 1000, 800"        ; # save the image size as 800*1000

"set output '${REPORT_DIR}/Test_Coverage_Curve_${atpg_mode}.png'"

"replot"